# How to keep the same speed of object when number of object increase?

Tags: android

Im doing a game and I'm using `SurfaceView`. In the game I have 25 small dots that are moving around. The goal is to make a game where the player draw a circle around some of the dots with the same color. My problem is that while I draw this circle and after I have lift my finger from the screen, all the dots are moving very, very slow! I guess the reason for this is all the line segmets that are being drawn constantly together with all the dots.

Is it possible to have the same moving speed of the dots all the time? I tested with `SystemClock.Sleep(1)` but it didn't helped much.

```
// Method to draw objects
private void drawObjects(Canvas canvas) {
    SystemClock.sleep(1);
    synchronized (this) {

    // Clear screen with black color
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    // Draw line
    if(startDrawLine) {
        // Set properties to Paint object
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        // Draw path
        path.moveTo(touchDownX, touchDownY);
        for(Point point: points) {
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }   
        path.reset();
    }
}
    // Call method draw() in CircleManager to draw all circles in list
    circleManager.drawCirclesInList(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow drawing is caused by to many points in your path.
If you are handling `Touch` event, you can expect hundreds and thousands of touches (your points) in short period of time.

1. You need to interpolate your points somehow - take averages, ignore same and close points or something else.
2. When you animate the "dots" your **ANIMATION MUST BE BASED ON TIME**, and not on the actual speed of the drawing on hardware.

To base your animation on time, you should calculate time passed since previous frame and use this time in function which calculates new position of the dot.
Here is a great article on the subject:
http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

**EDIT - Response to a comment:**

Suppose that your **"dot"** (I will call it a **ball**) needs to move horizontally (by `X`) from left to right at a constant speed of `100` units per second.

If you are doing your calculation **WITH ASSUMPTION** that your game will be running at **25 FPS**, you simply add `4` to `X` on each frame.

The problem with this approach is that **getting constant FPS is very hard to achieve.**
On the fast hardware you will be sacrificing smoothness by limiting FPS, 
on slow hardware you will be forced to skip drawing (drop) some frames (which can be jumpy with constant FPS).

Timer in Android is not very precise and also thread sleep functions are inaccurate.
In your case, instead of trying to force the constant FPS or calculate current FPS, try to wrap your head around and rethink of your problem 
in a context of time.

> When you think about time, it does not matter how fast is the game
>   running (how many FPS) and what happened before.
>
> You just need to ask a question "Where the ball should be in this
>   moment, right now?"

If you, for example, know that ball movement stared at origin position `X0` at origin time `T0` then at the current moment `TC` ball position should be `X = (TC - T0) * 100`

Second approach is to measure time passed `TD` since last ball position update. Then the ball position should be updated like this: `X = X + TD * 100`

Once you get used to this approach, you will see that vast majority of animations is really trivial to implement with a great level of accuracy.

Comment: I use LogCat to count the amount of points, and it's "only" around 50 points if I draw a circle. That's not much!?

Comment: Dusan, Is there a better way to do this? Preciate if you can show me? Perhasp it's my code that slow thing down!?

Comment: For the start, try to move canvas.drawPath(path, paint); out of the loop, put it after the loop.

Comment: I would also like to add that I'm implementing Runnable and use the method run() and a while loop for the game loop. I'm looking at your link. Does this mean that my objects moves faster on a "better" divice compared to an cheaper and slower device?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you have not used "time" component in "dot" position calculation then on fast hardware "dots" will be moving fast and on slow hardware will be moving "slow".

Comment: Dusan! I'm so glad you found this "error"! Now it's working much better! :)

Comment: OK, then in future also try keep your path simple as possible to get "smooth" animation.

Comment: Is it possible for me to add some code to the run() method to control the FPS of the game loop?

Comment: I'm just curious and want to learn. As my code is now, could you say that my objects speed is depending on the frame rate? But if I add some code to base them on time instead, then it's not depending on the frame rate!? Is there a way to measue the FPS?